# Couldn't find active user in search, a bug maybe?

Tags: support, bug, search, users

Why can't I find user "[Edgar Rokyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5507349/edgar-rokyan)"?

The guy exists but even copying and pasting the user name straight from the profile page to the search box fails to find him:

[image]

Google could find it:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Search for `Edgar  Rokyan` (two spaces)

Comment: Same @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, copy pasted from your comment.

Comment: Type the two spaces. They get collapsed into one in the comment.

Comment: 37 pages of "Edgar"s but entering his last name [worked](http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=5&tab=reputation&filter=week&search=rokyan).

Comment: That was it, thanks guys. I posted an answer, but anybody wants to post one, go ahead, I will favor it. Especially you, Roger, with the nice link! ;)

Comment: Here's a related SO Q&A: [Why do multiple spaces in an HTML file show up as single spaces in the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/433493/1842065)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå - that reminds me of a website where userids have to be a minimum of 3 characters, but it allowed me to use 3 spaces (without any other characters).  It really confuses the spots where they try to use my display name to create a hyperlink to my user profile! :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The search engine treats:

```
Edgar  Rokyan
```

differently from:

```
Edgar Rokyan
```

The latter has one space, and not two as the user's name...

Comment: This should probably be considered a bug, but it is correct.

Comment: It's all about the πολιτική of the search @EdCottrell. =)

Comment: @EdCottrell why should the user search algorithm care about spaces? It seems to me that the search was correct, and while it may be less than intuitive in such rare circumstances, I don't think there is enough reason to add complexity to the algorithm.

Comment: @TinyGiant Well, technically it may be a correct result, but I'd argue it violates user expectations.

Comment: @EdCottrell If anything, multiple spaces should be automatically compressed in usernames.

Comment: @TinyGiant No argument there.

Comment: @tiny *"why should the user search algorithm care about spaces"* Exactly. It **is** caring about spaces here, such that it matches the entry with *two* spaces, but not the entry with only *one* space. That's the bug.

Comment: @CodyGray, no in that respect it is treating spaces like every other character. If there was two r's in a row and you searched for one, would you expect it to return the correct result?

Comment: @TinyGiant Spaces should be treated specially because usernames are displayed in HTML, which collapses spaces due to the default `white-space: normal`.

Comment: @Oriol That makes no sense. The search is correct. The fact that multiple spaces are allowed in usernames even though those spaces will *never be shown under normal circumstances* is the problem here. Why cure the symptom by adding complexity to the search when you can cure the problem by removing unnecessary complexity from the usernames?

Comment: @TinyGiant I just meant that displaying usernames with collapsed spaces but requiring them to be written uncollapsed in search is not consistent. I'm not opposed to entirely forbidding multiple spaces